# How to get label control value from gridview templatefield

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

I have a templatefield column and below the textbox of edit item template I have a simple label .

Is there any way of getting the label value in ROW UPDATING event?

I've tried : `String llbl = ((Label)row.Cells[6].FindControl("label1")).Text;`
Hmm I think it shouldnt be `cells[6]` since I want to get the label .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;

Label Mylabel = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblName");
```

Edit:

OK, try this then:

```
GridViewRow row = MyGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Label MyLabel = (Label)row.FindControl("MyLabel");
```

Comment: aw my bad , sorry , I mean ROW UPDATING not row editing , I'm sorry . so I can't access e.Row in updating

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridItemEventArgs to find the label. Here is the code for UpdateCommand:

```
 private void grid_UpdateCommand(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
          Label label1 = (Label) e.Item.FindControl("label1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in RowEditing:

```
Label label1 = (Label)GridViewID.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("label1");
string label1val = label1.Text;
```

I believe this is what you want for RowUpdating:

```
Label label1 = (Label)GridViewID.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("label1");
string label1val = label1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
It's always works for me

```
string lbl =((Label)gvEmployee.Rows[rowNo].Cells[0].FindControl("lblEmpid")).Text;
```